# Find forms with jQuery in table row

Tags: jquery

i try run a function for each form in a table where the user has checked the checkbox in the first cell of the same row. However i can not find the forms with jQuery.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="checker" value=""></td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td><form class="ajax_form"></form></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="checker" value=""></td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td><form class="ajax_form"></form></td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

I tried

```
$('.checker:checkbox:checked').closest('form').each(function() {
      ...}
```

also with .find() and .next() but i get no result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the `tr` which contains the checkbox using [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method and then find out the form inside using [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```
$('.checker:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').find('form').each(function() {
   //...
});
```

Comment: yes! i never can remeber to go to the parent container first. i will glue this on my table now. thanks very much!!

Comment: @chicky :  glad to help you :)